# annotate_figure titles overlap ggplot titles

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am looking to join a number of ggplot figures using `ggpubr`. However I am finding that the titles generated in `ggplot` (using `labs()`) overlap with the title generated in `annotate_figure` (using `fig.lab =`).

Here is a reproducible example:

```
#import libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

#create data
data <- data.frame('type' = c('A', 'B', 'C'), 
                   'value' = c(1, 2, 3))
#create figure
fig <- ggplot(data, 
              aes(x = type, y = value)) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = 'My title') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
        
#arrange figure (in my real case i would actually be sticking plots together)       
arrange_fig <- ggarrange(fig)

#annotate plots
annotate_figure(arrange_fig,
  fig.lab = 'My main title',
  fig.lab.pos = 'top')
```

Result is:[image]

You can see the titles clearly overlapping.

I realize in my example, i don't need to center the ggplot title, but in my real case, I arrange three plots, each with a title and these then clash with the `annotate_figure title` (`fig.pos =`). This would be the case regardless of where I position the `annotate_figure` title. Effectively I need to move it 'up'.

I can't find a solution online and I am amazed I have not had this issue previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to switch to `patchwork`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

data <- data.frame(
  "type" = c("A", "B", "C"),
  "value" = c(1, 2, 3)
)
fig <- ggplot(
  data,
  aes(x = type, y = value)
) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "My title") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

fig + plot_annotation(
  title = "My main title",
  theme = theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
  )
)
```

[image]

```r
fig + fig + fig + plot_annotation(
  title = "My main title",
  theme = theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works. I have opened an issue on github ggpubr to see if they generate a solution: https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/500